# C preprocessor macros are treated as comments in code blocks?

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, markdown-rendering

Am I doing this wrong, or is the syntax coloring support for macros subpar? They look to be treated as comments when the argument is only a single word, but multi-word arguments are highlighted differently.

Can this be fixed by, e.g., updating the version of prettify?

```
// plain code block
int foo() {
#if this_looks_like_a_comment
    return 1;
#elif "but this does not"
    return 2;
#endif
}
```

```c
// preceded by <!-- language: lang-c -->
int foo() {
#if this_looks_like_a_comment
    return 1;
#elif "but this does not"
    return 2;
#endif
}
```

```objc
// preceded by <!-- language: lang-objc -->
int foo() {
#if this_looks_like_a_comment
    return 1;
#elif "but this does not"
    return 2;
#endif
}
```

Comment: This also occurs with the shebang (`#!`) in shell script questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with single vs. multiple words; highlighting is broken for the `#if` directive:

```c
#define this_works
#if this_doesnt
```

Updating the version of prettify won't work because [the code](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/prettify.js#L925) is still broken:

```js
/* elif, endif, ifdef, ifndef, but no if! */
/^#(?:(?:define|e(?:l|nd)if|else|error|ifn?def|include|line|pragma|undef|warning)\b|[^\r\n]*)/
```

code-prettify no longer [appears to be dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251321/234299), so you can submit a ticket/patch/PR, but who knows if Stack Overflow will actually update to a newer version. The [last request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264356/234299) to update sank into oblivion.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to do about this. Treating these as comments seems like a bad approach, but it looks to be very ingrained in how prettify works — there's no other class defined that would really match the case of these directives. But I'm guessing the chance of switching to any other highlighting system is near-zero...